# Observable Array Value Update

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

For a timesheet application I have an observable array:

DayHrs

DayHrs contains either 5 or 7 days depending on the employee.
I have a total WeekHrs which is a calculated field.

When a user enters a value for one of the DayHrs, I want the total WeekHrs field to update straight away.

So in my data-bind I want to use valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'.

However I cannot make this a computed field as the array items in the observable array are not themselves observable.

According to the Knockout documentation: Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects.

So how do I fix this? Is there a way to iterate through the array to make each item observable (I haven't seen how to do this) or should I specify a change event? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways of converting "plain javascript objects" into viewmodels with observable properties:

1. Automatically, via `ko.mapping.fromJS`, or
2. Manually.

I'll give an answer if you want to go with option 2. If you want to do it automatically (1), it's probably best to have a look at the documentation and examples [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

In the code below I've coded an example that converts plain javascript objects and arrays to `ko.observable` and `ko.observableArray` properties. Each viewmodel has a constructor or static `create` method that "knows" how to deal with a specified data format. For each property in your data you can chose to either:

1. Ignore it (it doesn't serve a purpose in your viewmodel when it's not rendered in a view)
2. Make it a regular property (when it's rendered statically in your view)
3. Make it observable (when it needs to be updated in the view)

Then, you can add `ko.computed` properties and methods to make your view interactive.

```js
var Day = function(initialHours) {
  this.hours = ko.observable(initialHours || 0);
};

Day.create = function(data) {
  return new Day(data.Hours);  
}

var Week = function(initialDays) {
  this.days = ko.observableArray(initialDays.map(Day.create));
  
  this.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.days().reduce(function(sum, day) {
      return sum + parseInt(day.hours(), 10);
    }, 0);
  }, this);
};
    
Week.create = function(dayArray) {
  return new Week(dayArray);
};

var Employee = function(employeeData) {
  this.name = employeeData.Name;
  this.workWeek = Week.create(employeeData.WorkWeek);
};

Employee.create = function(employeeData) {
  return new Employee(employeeData);
};

var testData = [{
  Name: "John Doe",
  WorkWeek: [
    { Hours: 4 },
    { Hours: 8 },
    { Hours: 8 },
    { Hours: 8 },
    { Hours: 6 }
  ]
}];
  
var vm = {
  employees: testData.map(Employee.create)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
input[type="number"] { width: 30px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<ul data-bind="foreach: employees">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="with: workWeek">
      <!-- ko foreach: days -->
      <input data-bind="value: hours" type="number"/> -
      <!-- /ko -->
      <span data-bind="text: 'total: ' + totalHours()"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```